# Difference between FlowDirection="{Binding}" and FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}"

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to bind the `FlowDirection` of the parent control to each and every set of it's child components's `FlowDirection` The former code works fine and the later also does the same. What is the effective way to bind the parentControl's property value to it's child components ( textBoxexs, comboBoxes, popUps,etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlowDirection is an inherited property, so you do not need to manually set FlowDirection on child components.

> An object inherits the FlowDirection value from its parent in the object tree.

Source: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement)

Comment: Hi David, I had also gone through the article, actually I'm using a custom control and so want to know the effective binding implementation. Other than `FlowDirection` consider the `Text` property of the parent control. If I want to bind that, which method will be effective and how it works?

Comment: If you are binding to a property on the control itself, you should use TemplateBinding (you can only use this inside a ControlTemplate). TemplateBindings are evaluated at compile time instead of runtime, so it is more efficient.